# Relation Between Two Tables: make relationship between two tables

Tags: mysql, database-design, yii

I have two tables as **post** and **gallery**, and i have made a relationship gallery to post table.
My requirement is,
When user upload content it store in the post table(content field) ,
If user upload the images are video i want to store the images/video name in, gallery table and the gallery id refers to the post table. I dont know how to do it. please any one help me?

**post table:**

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `post` (
`id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`user_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
`gallery_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,

`content` longtext,
`photo` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
`video` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,

`created` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`updated` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `fk_forum_post_user` (`user_id`),
KEY `fk_forum_post_gallery` (`gallery_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=10 ;

ALTER TABLE `post`
ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_post_gallery` FOREIGN KEY (`gallery_id`) REFERENCES `gallery`    (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
```

**gallery table**

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `gallery` (
`id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`user_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
`type` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' COMMENT '1- Photo, 2-Video, 3-Documents, 4-Unknown',


`profile_picture` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`forum_image` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
`forum_video` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
`forum_video_link` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,

`created` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`updated` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `fk_gallery_user` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=60 ;
```

is any other idea is to do or how can i move forward?

Comment: you have not done anything yet,? or can you past3 a samlpe of your model code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of ways you can perform this tasks. you can perform logic on code level as well as on database level. however here is a quick answer . hope this could help you

- First Remove the column  (`gallery_id`) as it is possible that user may have more than one images or video for single post or user may not want to upload any image / video in this case your gallery id would be null.
- In this case your Pk would be only postId
- your gallery table is fine
- Make a third table name PostGalleryRealation
- make 2 column in this table PostId as fk from post table and galleryid as fk from gallery table.
- this is basically for one to many relation as one post may have more than one gallery
- insert the post id and gallery id in PostGalleryRealation table
- Finally you can write this query to fetch the result for you.

I did not test the query, so it's just a basic idea

```sql
 Select p.id, p.content, p.created, g.type, g.profilepicture, g.forum_image 
   from post p, gallery g, postgalleryrelation pgr 
  where p.id = pgr.postid 
    and g.id = pgr.galleryid
    and p.id = 1
```

It's just an idea. You can do much better.

Comment: thanks for your reply..
now i'm getting the following error:
( ! ) Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting! in C:\wamp\framework\db\CDbCommand.php on line 103

Answer (score 0):

YII have  `relation` option while creating `CRUD` using `gii`. For that, you have to create tables with foreign key relationship. So YII will automatically create the relation in coding level. You have to choose the option `Build Relation` while creating model for both tables.

Check the [Yii relation tutorials](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr) for more information